# No such file or directory OR TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: loops, directory, python-2.6

In python 2.6:

I haven't been able to implement any of the responses to other posts with this error and make it work so I need direct help here with my code. I know basics of python and I'm trying to write my own script to

1. open a folder
2. list all the files in the folder
3. open the files one by one and count in each file unique entries.

I create a dictionary with each entry stored as a key and values being the total number of times each entry is present. I then ask to print for the length of the dictionary to know how many unique entries there are. The dictionary works but the loop through the folder doesn't. Basically it tells me that there is not such file or directory or the error below:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python      
    import sys
    import os

    # Takes files in a folder and counts unique records in each file, returns the number of each record followed by the name of the file
    ##usage: perl countunique.py folder
    folder = (sys.argv[1])
    list = open(os.listdir(folder), "rU")

    for filename in list:
        count = {}
        for gene in filename:
            if not gene in count :
                    count[gene]=1
            else:
                    count[gene]+=1           
    print( "There are {0} unique entries in {1}".format(len(count.keys()), f))
```

list = open(os.listdir(folder), "rU")

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Thank you in advance

Edited:

I also try:

```
folder = (sys.argv[1])
list = os.listdir(folder)
for filename in list:
    file = open(filename, "rU")
    count = {}
    for gene in file:
            if not gene in count :
                    count[gene]=1
            else:
                    count[gene]+=1

    print( "There are {0} unique entries in {1}".format(len(count.keys()), filename))
```

and I get this error:
file = open(filename, "rU")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.renamed'

file1.renamed is actually in the folder so I don't know why it can't find it.

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list; you can't `open` a list.

Comment: ok @jonrsharpe I tried something different - edited the original post

Comment: Please edit the question to be more coherent - there's now a whole chunk of it that doesn't relate to your current issue. Also, you should do some research - is the directory in question actually in Python's path? Why not use the fully-qualified location to remove ambiguity?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

folder = sys.argv[1]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in files:
            filePath = folder + '/' + filename
            file = open(filePath, "rU")
            count = {}
            for gene in file:
                    if not gene in count :
                            count[gene]=1
                    else:
                            count[gene]+=1    
            print( "There are {0} unique entries in {1}".format(len(count.keys()), filename))
```